# how to print multiple max values using loop

Tags: c

Trying to calculate at which frequencies voltage hits max, i am able to print the most recent max but there may be lower values of frequency in which it is able to max voltage.

I am able to get the highest or lowest freq by switching the loop from + to - from or to 1000000 in increments of 10.

Tried nested if statement inside of `VO > voMax`

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14f
#define Vi 5

#define L 4.3e-4
#define C 5.1e-6

int getFreq();
long getResist();
float getVO(float XL, float XC, int R);
float getXC(int f);
float getXL(int f);

int main()
{
    long resist, freq, fMax;
    float XL, XC, VO, voMax;

    voMax = 0;
    fMax = 0;
    resist = getResist();
    for (freq = 1000000; freq >= 0; freq -= 10)
    {
        XL = getXL(freq);

        XC = getXC(freq);

        VO = getVO(XL, XC, resist);
        if (1000000 == freq)
        {
            fMax = freq;
            voMax = VO;

        }
        else if (VO > voMax)
        {
            fMax = freq;
            voMax = VO;

        }       
    }
    printf("VO = %f Frequency = %d\n", voMax, fMax);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

float getXL(long f)
{
    float XL;

    XL = 2 * PI * f * C;
    return XL;
}

float getXC(long f)
{
    float XC;

    XC = 1 / (2 * PI * f * C);
    return XC;

}

float getVO(float XL, float XC, long R)
{
    float VO;

    VO = (Vi * R) / sqrt((XL - XC) * (XL - XC) + R * R);
    return VO;
}

int getFreq()
{
    int freq;
    freq = 0;
    printf("please enter a frequency:");
    scanf("%d", &freq);
    return freq;
}
long getResist()
{
    int resist;
    resist = 0;
    printf("please enter a resistance:");
    scanf("%d", &resist);
    return resist;
}
```

I want the voltage to print max at multiple freq.

Comment: Not sure whether I got this right. To print local maxima, you have to compare a value with its predecessor and successor. If it's greater than both, you found a local maximum (and could print it immediately i.e. inside the loop).

Comment: function getXL() uses C instead of L, I assume ;)

Comment: You want to print a list of all `freq` (not only the last one) at which the global (not local) maximum occurs? Can you somehow define a maximum number of occurences?

Comment: By the way, I assume that this might be a homework assignment to calculate resonance frequency. If that is the case then try using math instead of trying via simulaiton. I.e. do not loop over imaginable frequencies, use the given values to calculate. Feel free to comment on my speculations.

Comment: If there is a circuit with resistor, capacity and inductivity involved, consider showing some ascii-art of that circuit. Some people here might know about electrical enginerring and help you with matching the code to the circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you want is to generate "a lot" of data, and then make some analysis. I would actually implement it in two steps:

1. Generate the data (and save it in an array or in a file)
2. Do any analysis you need on that data.

After you get the desired result with this clear approach, you can move to the next step and try to optimize the algorithm, according to any optimization rule you need.

---

> I want the voltage to print max at multiple freq.

I think you need a small code update. You have the following sequence:

```
voMax = 0;
fMax = 0;
resist = getResist();
for (freq = 1000000; freq >= 0; freq -= 10)
{
```

you should probably have:

```
fMax = 0;
resist = getResist();
for (freq = 1000000; freq >= 0; freq -= 10)
{
    voMax = 0;
```

(I moved "voMax = 0;" inside the "for").

In that way, you can calculate max voltages for all frequencies, without interference from the other frequencies.

Comment: What is calculated for each frequency is VO, VOmax is the maximum of that over all frequencies. Resetting it each time is the part of your (otherwise good answer) which I don't get. It seems to defeat the whole purpose...

Comment: As I understand (the desired behavior is not excellently described) the OP wants more than one voMax. He can do it in 2 ways: save all voMax somewhere (array, file), or reset voMax for each iteration. In the end he will have to decide what to do with all the values.

Comment: i feel like an array would be more suitable but its for a school assignment so maybe im just trying to do too much,  im just trying to explore avenues. and ya thank you! were right about the XL function, i changed mine!

Comment: If you find anything unclear about OP, then please use your commenting privilege to clarify. I think this answer is based on a risky assumption.

Comment: To avoid the risky assumptions, I provided alternatives. OP can choose the suitable one according to his very specific needs.

Comment: babySteps If you think doing it by using an array instead of the method here would be better, then I think you did not get the point of this answer.

Comment: virolino I could upvote the data-collection via large array (then optimise) idea - though the optimisation would need to be non-trivial. However, the second part (which I consider being a separate and much less helpful answer) prevents me.

Comment: @Yunnosch: to use your own attitude: please use your privileges to provide a better answer. I will not mind if you have a better solution.

Comment: I did elaborate as much as I could already in comments here. I did ask for information on the question, which was not answered (hint babySteps) and hence cannot answer. Virolino consider splitting this and making a second answer. BabySteps accepting an answer is supposed to express that it helped you. I get the feeling that this is not applicable - yet. (Sorry virolino.)

Comment: Privileges are not needed for answering. Asking for clarity beforehand needs a minor privilege, which you (virolino) have already.

Comment: I fail to understand why it is bad to rest voMax for calculating maximums for each frequency, instead of calculating one max for all frequencies - considering that OP wants more than 1 max.

Comment: I assume that the background is to determine via simulation the resonance frequency of a capacitor-inductivity circuit. This is what the shown code more or less does. There is no maximum voltage for each frequency, there is nothing more complex you can do for each frequency (there is e.g. no sensible inner loop to do on each). There is only the possibility, in OPs mind, that the maximumm could occur more than once, which is true if OP gets unlucky with the choice of sample frequencies. The only need is to list all (of the few) frequencies which in this simulation have the max voltage.

Comment: And the fact that I started with "I assume..." means I need clarification, more info, more explanation, confirmation of my assumption, ... before I can answer. My doubt that resetting at each frequency makes sense for what I assume meanwhile keeps me from upvoting the answer.

Comment: 1. I do not have to ask for clarifications in your name 2. If you have doubts, ask specific questions or clarify them by yourself. 3. You have the freedom to test the code, and verify if it works or not. It is that simple.